# MacOS's counterpart to Linux's unshare(2)

Tags: networking, osx, c, system-calls

Does MacOS have a counterpart to Linux's [unshare(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unshare)?

I'd like for the following to fail on both systems.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
int main()
{
#if __linux__
    if(0>unshare(CLONE_NEWNET)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
#elif __APPLE__
    /*?*/
#endif
    //this should fail on either system
    if(0!=system("curl www.google.com")) return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: I have to wonder if https://apple.stackexchange.com/ might be better for this... but I dunno!

Comment: I don't think OS X support namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac OS X doesn't really have namespaces like Linux, but if you want to block networking, it looks like you can use `sandbox_init()` to get a similar effect. See the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/sandbox_init/) for a description.

There are two built-in profiles that seem to support a use case similar to what you describe: `kSBXProfileNoInternet`, where    TCP/IP networking is prohibited; and `kSBXProfileNoNetwork`, where all sockets-based networking is prohibited. (While the latter might be closer to what Linux network namespace is doing here, the former might be enough for your needs.)

Please note that this function is documented as *deprecated*, and those who wish to sandbox an application should look into the [App Sandbox feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html), so you might want to take a look at that as well. I don't know that App Sandbox would use the same mechanism (code that you run from a platform `#ifdef`), that's why I suggested `sandbox_init()` first.